# Format causing issues when converting to datetime (data_string[found.end():]))

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, strptime

I am loading lots of csv files, which I want to plot, that have column titles representing date and time.

For example:

```
14/01/2015 14:27    14/01/2015 14:27
29.97299    30.05902
30.00391    30.09555
```

For some reason, different files get these dates and times loaded in different formats and I am running into trouble when converting them.

My current code:

```
for n, f in enumerate(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(filePath+f, delimiter=',',index_col=0)
    times = []
    print df.columns.values[1]
    for i, t in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        if t[2]=='/':
            time = datetime.strptime(t, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        elif t[4]=='-':
            time = datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        else:
            print "Is it a date? ", t
        times.append(time)
    timelists.append(times)
    fig = plt.figure()
    df.plot()
    plt.savefig(figdir+(n+1).__str__()+"_"+f+".png", bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300)
    print "Fig", n+1
    plt.close(n)
```

Produces this:

```
2015-01-14 10:50:19
Fig 1
2015-01-14 14:01:15
Fig 2
2015-01-14 14:13:08
Fig 3
2015-01-14 14:27:53
Fig 4
2015-01-14 14:40:00
Fig 5
15/01/2015 13:03
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Followed by an error (with traceback):

```
  File "D:/data/scripts/myscript.py", line 29, in <module>
    time = datetime.strptime(t, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\_strptime.py", line 335, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])

ValueError: unconverted data remains: .1
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error, the last date that is printed is in the format I specify, is it not? and what does the `data_string[found.end():])` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means `strptime` is converting a string that has more information in it than specified in the format, such as seconds or microseconds. For example I get the same error if I try to push '14/01/2015 14:27:00.000' through `strptime` with the format `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M`. To make this work in my example I need to use the following format with `strptime` - `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f`.

Not sure exactly what your files are like but the pandas library has very good date/time comprehension. I am not sure if I have exactly had your problem before but in my experience it usually guesses the format correctly without too much (if any) fussing.

EDIT: Actually if you read the file snippet you posted with pandas it will make the dates the column names and it will append `.1` to the second column because the column names should be unique. It seems like that `.1` is exactly the part of the date\time string that is not captured by the format specified in the call to `strptime`. So maybe you are already using pandas at some point in your processing. Please note that pandas will not make the column names `datetime` objects by default, it will assume they are strings.

Comment: You are right! I am editing the question. So the problem is why does pandas read the files with different formats, when visually (if I open them in excel) they look the same. Or perhaps a new question...

Comment: Ok, one faulty datafile that does not have the seconds, which is why it is read in a different format. Now it should work. Thanks!